# iOS Swift splash screen from Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

In my iPhone app need to display a splash screen (displays company logo and some info) for 2-3 seconds before load the first page.

Also the app needs to decide which page should load as the first page in here (according the 'initial setup completion' level by the user).

I am using 'Swift' as the programing language and 'Universal StoryBoard' to design interfaces...

I have seleted the Main.storyboard as the Launch Screen File. In the ViewController class have implemented following logic

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSLog("Before sleep...")
    sleep(2)
    NSLog("After sleep...")

    self.controllNavigation()
}

func controllNavigation() -> Void {

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var nextViewController  

    if (Condition1)
    {
        nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenu") as! MainMenuViewController
    }
    else
    {
        nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserSetup") as! UserSetupViewController
    }

    self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

All works ok but While waiting with `sleep(2)`, refresh page sort of a thing happens. I am not sure if this is the best way to do. Like to hear ideas. Thanks

Comment: You're not a user pleaser are you... 2-3 seconds pause? Just let the user in! Or you'll be heading for 1 star reviews. Users don't want to look at your company logo or info for any time, they presumably want to use your app.

Comment: hi Daniel, yes I understand that. But that's the customer requirement. Their Android and windows apps doing that. Need the same functionality in IOS app.

Comment: Why dont you use the Launch Screen as it should be, so it does not irritate users, and goes away as soon as the app has loaded?

Comment: Hi  longbow 8, yes could use. But need to implement that logic (to decide which page should load as first). Also needs to implement that 2 seconds delay.

Comment: You should find yourself a more respectable customer. Don't forget, the customer is not the company, it's the user :) /rant over/ Please forgive me I know I'm of no help to you, I'm just crazy about a great User Experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the delay in app delegate instead of viewController's viewDidAppear.
Use as:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    NSLog("Before Sleep");
    sleep(2);
    NSLog("After sleep");
    return true
}
```

Doing this will allow your splash screen to stay till 2 seconds and then you can use following in your view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   self.controllNavigation()
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: don't use sleep(3), it freezes main thread. use `performSelector: afterDelay:`

Comment: Yes @KostiantynKoval, he want to stay on launch screen till 2 seconds, so he need to freeze main thread. He can't use perform selector because it will take him on ViewController directly.

Comment: Of course there are proper ways of doing this e.g. you may create a UIViewController to show your launch screen and from there you can push your desire viewController after 2 seconds, but using sleep will work without extra overhead.

Comment: @KostiantynKoval Doesn't work with non-objc Swift methods.

Comment: sleep is really bad decision because it makes your app dead. I would prefer to show the UIViewController wit the image of splash screen.
This way you could add extra animation or smt else later. Also you can use this solution for delay 
dispatch_after(0.1, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // your function here
})

Answer (score 2):

I came across similar answers which mentioned `sleep()`, however it doesn't seem appropriate to use as it blocks the main thread.

I came up with this solution if you are using the default LaunchScreen.storyboard in Xcode 7.2:

```
func showLaunchScreen() {
    let launchScreen = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil)
    let launchView = launchScreen.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.view.addSubview(launchView!.view)

    let timeDelay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(timeDelay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { _ in
            launchView?.view.alpha = 0.0
            }) { _ in
                launchView!.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

This will show the launch screen for another 2 seconds, then fade it out over 0.5 seconds. You can call you other function to load the 'default' VC in the completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue with this:

On my project I set the desired storyboard of splash (in my case Splash.storyboard) as Default Screen -> Targets/ (your target)/ Info/ Launch Screen Interface File Base Name.

[Field on Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgy4b.png)

When you've done that, you can insert your logic on method "func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {} " placed on AppDelegate.swift .

If you want to make clean code, you can insert all your navigation related methods on another Class, and call them from AppDelegate.swift .

With this solution, the splash is visible only the required time, and when it finish, you can navigate to the screen you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 Update  100% working**

Just write one line of code
`Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3.0)`
 in the method of `didfinishLauching....` in `appdelegate` class.

**Example**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3.0)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```